# compare list values with dictionories python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a list and dictionary

```
   lis = ["abc","bcd fg","cda"]
   dic = {1:"dcbagh",2:"cd abc", 3:"fg"}
```

I want to compare the list values with a dictionary values and return a new dictionary like below,

```
res_dic = {1:"none" ,2:"abc" , 3:"bcd fg"}
```

We need to return a corresponding string even if matches slightly. I have tried with the following method. But nothing worked out.

```
n = {}
for k,v in dic.items():
    for i in lis:
        if i==k:
            n[k] = v
```

this is another method

```
n = {k: d[k] for k in d.keys() & set(lis)}
```

Comment: Don't use `dict` as a variable name, you're overwriting the built-in function.

Comment: I had deleted but still, it's not working

Comment: The condition should be `if v in i:`

Comment: That was just a general comment, nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: I am getting empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition is wrong. `if i == k` compares the list element with the dictionary key, but you want to compare with the value, which is `v`. And you don't need an exact match, you're looking for a substring, so you should be using `in` rather than `==`. Since you seem to allow either string to be a substring of the other, use `if v in i or i in v:`

And the value you assign in the result is supposed to be the list element, not the dictionary value.

But you also want to use the value `"none"` if no match is found. So you need to break out of the loop when you find a match, and use `else:` to assign a value if the loop completes without breaking.

```
n = {}
for k,v in dic.items():
    for i in lis:
        if v in i or i in v:
            n[k] = i
            break
    else:
        n[k] = "none"
```

Comment: this is the result `{1: 'none', 2: 'none', 3: 'bcd fg'}` while the op was expecting this `{1:"none" ,2:"abc" , 3:"bcd fg"}`

Comment: I know, I just asked him about that.

Comment: `{1:"none" ,2:"abc" , 3:"bcd fg"}` I am expecting something like this... even if matches slightly also we should return